# Looking to a build a simple find and replace program for file paths using Python

Tags: python, replace, find, slash

I think I should start this off by saying that I'm very new to Python. I've gone through some lessons and picked up a fairly solid understanding of the fundamentals, but my skill set is still very limited and the results I achieve on my own will probably be very crude. I'm currently trying to put together a find and replace program that can output edited paths. See below:

```
filepaths = [
"\wwwtest\test\site\services\cogs\index.html",
"\wwwtest\test\site\dba\index.html"
]

find = "\wwwtest\test\site"

replace_one = "http:\\www.test.com"

replace_two = "https:\\www.test.com"

for paths in filepaths:
    print(paths.replace(find, replace_one))
    print(paths.replace(find, replace_two))
```

So in essence, what I'm trying to do is input file paths and output URLs. Running the above code in a shell yields the following results:

```
http:\www.test.com\services\cogs\index.html
https:\www.test.com\services\cogs\index.html
http:\www.test.com\dba\index.html
https:\www.test.com\dba\index.html
```

I think I'm more or less on the right track, but obviously there are some issues with the output, namely the removal of the second \ preceding the www of each URL. I imagine that this is the result of Python interpreting the double \ as some kind of special character, but I've been unable to determine how best to resolve this issue.

Following the successful replacement of the first block of the path/URL, I'll also need to replace each \ with / (or maybe this should come first?) which is creating its own set of issues. The following code is what I've tried so far:

```
urls = [
    "http:\www.test.com\services\cogs\index.html",
    "https:\www.test.com\services\cogs\index.html"
    ]

find = '\'

replace = '/'

for paths in urls:
    print(paths.replace(find, replace))
```

This code yields the following:

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

I believe I'm missing some information regarding the use of slashes in Python. Any advice on how best to develop such a program, and also how to make the code efficient would be very much appreciated. I also realize that hard coding the paths I want to manipulate into the program probably isn't the most effective way of doing this, but I may leave that for a separate question to keep this post from getting longer than it already is (although any advice on how to properly read from and write to text files for this example would also be appreciated).

Thank you,
D

Comment: `find = '\'`: the backslash escapes the closing `'`. If you mean an actual backslash, escape it: `find = '\\'`. See e.g. http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html

Answer (score 0):

In python, `\` is the escape character, so if you want to literally represent `\` you have to repeat it twice, i.e. `"C:\\Windows\\path"` or define it as a string literal in place by putting an `r` before the string, `r"C:\Windows\path"`

[Here](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html) are some good examples to show you how it operates.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Of the two solutions, it seems like adding an `r` before the string is the more elegant one, but it doesn't seem to be working. After adding `r` in front of each variable string from the code above, it still throws back a SyntaxError. My reluctance in using \\ to represent a single \ is that it would require me to manually edit the file paths before running them through the Python program, which is arguably more work than the program is performing itself.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is the beginning of an [escape sequence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

In the first part if you wish to output two `"\\"` you will need to write it like this:

```
replace_one = "http:\\\\www.test.com"

replace_two = "https:\\\\www.test.com"
```

if you wish to find a `\` you will need to do it like this to escape the escape sequence:

```
find = '\\'
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you want to use `\`, use instead `\\`.  Consequently, if you want `\\`, use `\\\\`:

```
filepaths = [
"\\wwwtest\\test\\site\\services\\cogs\\index.html",
"\\wwwtest\\test\\site\\dba\\index.html"
]

find = "\\wwwtest\\test\\site"

replace_one = "http:\\\\www.test.com"

replace_two = "https:\\\\www.test.com"

for paths in filepaths:
    print(paths.replace(find, replace_one))
    print(paths.replace(find, replace_two))
```

and

```
urls = [
    "http:\\\\www.test.com\\services\\cogs\\index.html",
    "https:\\\\www.test.com\\services\\cogs\\index.html"
    ]

find = '\\'

replace = '/'

for paths in urls:
    print(paths.replace(find, replace))
```

should fix your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your input! I added a comment to one of the other replies that suggested `r` may fix my problem, but I'm having trouble implementing that. As someone with more experience, do you have any suggestions for how to improve the functionality of this code? It seems as though doubling the slashes between file paths before feeding them into the program would somewhat defeat the purpose of the program.

Comment: It depends on how you are feeding them into your program.  If you are just typing them at the top of your file, you will always need either to use an `r` or to double the slashes.  The reason you will still have an error is that Python interprets `\'` *before* the `str` class does.  You will still need to use '\\' if '\' is the last character of your string.  If your urls are passed through `sys.argv` or are received through user input, they will already have double backslashes.  Your `find` variable, however, will always need either `r` or double backslashes.